# Test with Rspec let is failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot

I have problem with FactoryGirl and RSpec. I have following test:

```
require 'rails_helper'
describe Customer do
  it_behaves_like "Account"

  describe "it has an address" do
    let(:customer) {create(:customer)}
    let(:address) {create(:address, addressable_id: customer.id, addressable_type: "Account")}

    it "should have an address" do
      expect(customer.address).to eq address
    end
  end
end
```

When I try to run it throws me following error:

```
) Customer it has an address should have an address
     Failure/Error: expect(customer.address).to eq address

       expected: #<Address id: 1, street: "Street 1", zip_code: "11-111", city: "City 1", addressable_id: 1, addressable_type: "Account", created_at: "2014-09-26 10:07:51", updated_at: "2014-09-26 10:07:51">
            got: nil

       (compared using ==)
     # ./spec/models/customer_spec.rb:11:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

But when I refactor it to something like this:

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe Customer do
  it_behaves_like "Account"

  describe "it has an address" do
    before do
      @customer = create(:customer)
      @address = create(:address, addressable_id: @customer.id, addressable_type: "Account")
    end

    it "should have an address" do
      expect(@customer.address).to eq @address
    end
  end
end
```

It works properly. Why my example with let is failing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because `let` is evaluated lazily.

Calling `expect(customer.address)` invokes your first `let` block, i.e. `create(:customer)` . It returns a `customer` without an address.

The second `let` block `create(:address, ...)` is not invoked until calling `eq address`.

You can use [`let!`](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/helper-methods/let-and-let) to create the address instantly:

```
let!(:address) { create(:address, ...) }
```

Another option is to use a custom factory `customer_with_address` that sets the [association](http://rubydoc.info/gems/factory_girl/file/GETTING_STARTED.md#Associations).